# Instantiate prefab at random X and Y while not spawning on top of each other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm working on a game for school, an endless vertical platformer. The issue I'm having is that I can spawn platforms no problem but I can't seem to figure out how to get them to either move or destroy when spawned on top of each other.

```
public void SpawnPlatforms(float floatValue)
{
    yPos = spawnPlatformsTo;     
        while (yPos <= floatValue)
        {

            xPos = Random.Range(-4.5f, 4.5f);
            Vector2 posXY = new Vector2(xPos, yPos);


            var platformInstatiated = Instantiate(platforms[Random.Range(0, 2)], posXY, Quaternion.identity);

                platformInstatiated.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("Platforms").transform;
                platformInstatiated.localScale = new Vector3(Random.Range(.3f, 1f), 1, 1);

            yPos += Random.Range(1f, 1.75f);
        }

    spawnPlatformsTo = floatValue;
}
```

any help at all would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't give your variable types var, it is bad practice and would be better to give it the actual object type. In this case platformInstatiated should be GameObject.

Comment: Interesting. I was unaware of that, thanks for the tip. May I ask why that's considered bad practice?

Comment: It is just part of naming convention. It helps reduce the effort needed to read and understand source code. Programmers not familiar with unity but with C# wont know that Instantiate returns type GameObject for example, but that is just one of many reasons. It is the same reason you PascalCase your methods and camelCase your variables.

Comment: Perfect. Good to know, thanks a lot. I'm in school for video game design, not programming so this is all a little new to me. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Unity has a function for that called **Bounds.Intersects**.

Add all your platforms to a list or loop through all platforms in your scene and then check each one with

```
    //Fetch the Bounds from the Looped GameObject
    Bounds m_Bounds = loopedGameObject.GetComponent<Collider>().m_Collider.bounds;

    if(m_Bounds.Intersects(platformInstatiated.GetComponent<Collider>().bounds)
        Destroy(platformInstatiated);
        //Although you should really try to give it a new position instead of destroying it.
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking stupid questions, how would I go about adding all the instantiated objects to a list?

Comment: I was able to get them into a list using a for loop. The list prints out the proper count. The code you posted does not work though. specifically this code 

`Bounds m_Bounds = loopedGameObject.GetComponent<Collider>().m_Collider.bounds;`


Its a list so loopedGameObject doesn't work and neither does the end m_collider.bounds.